# Mocha contract testing error: Done() called multiple times in hook

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, smartcontracts

Hi I am new in the smart contract world, and I am having an issue with mocha.  This is a test that I am working on:

**-EDIT-**

```js
const UsersContract = artifacts.require("../contracts/UsersContract.sol");

contract("TestUsersContract", async accounts => {
    let instance;

    beforeEach('setup contract for each test', async () => {
        instance = await UsersContract.deployed();
    });

    it('should retrieve User', async () => {
        instance.join(1, "John Doe");
        instance.send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 50000 });

        let user = await instance.getUser(accounts[0]);
        assert.equal(user[0].toNumber(), 1);
        assert.equal(user[1], 'John Doe');
    });
});
```

This is throwing me the following errors:

```sh
    1) Uncaught Error: the string "abort(Error: Given input \"[object Object]\" is not a number.). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info." was thrown, throw an Error :)
    2) Error: done() called multiple times in hook
```

I don't know why, but when I refactor the test to  a non async version:

```js
it('should retrieve User', () => {
    instance.join(1, "John Doe");
    instance.send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 50000 });

    instance.getUser(accounts[0]).then( user => {
        assert.equal(user[0].toNumber(), 1);
        assert.equal(user[1], 'John Doe');
    });
});
```

Every thing goes smooth and the tests perform as expected. Why is happening this? Can an `async/await` version be done here or do I have to stick to the `.then()` version always?

A bit of enlightenment would be nice, thank you.

Comment: Is the error thrown when there is not another error?

Comment: Nope, are always paired.

Comment: Can you share more code? I can't reproduce the issue. Also, if you catch the exception, is the error still happening? Maybe the error trace call `done()` and that's why the error appears.

Comment: @J.F. Edited with the whole code.

Comment: hi.. any news about it? same issue here.. it works on mac but when run in an server gives me this error.. using selenium headless chrome